# JQuery UI removeClass Animation Not Working on Site But Working in JSFiddle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, removeclass

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f93j5/5/)

But on the site (http://c3denver.org/access/members/attendance) it is not working, any ideas?

Click on one of the boxes with someone's name on it, for example Scott, it turns green, but when I click again, it should turn red and fade back to grey, according to jQuery(this).removeClass('transition',400);.

It works in the fiddle but not on the site.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.attendance .form .grid_padding label').click(function(evt){
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
        if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('attending')){
            jQuery('input', this).prop('checked', true);
            jQuery(this).addClass('attending');
        }else{
            jQuery(this).addClass('transition').removeClass('attending');
            jQuery(this).removeClass('transition',400);
            jQuery('input', this).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not included jquery-ui.js and stylesheet pleasse include these

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.csss">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: jQuery ui was being loaded.  I also added the stylesheet, but it is still not working on the site.